# grep "Sound On" && echo "do something" command does not give me result

Tags: bash, grep

I tried to see if radio station is broadcasting silence.
Due to this test purpose I removed `--quiet` from grep and reversed `Sound Off` to `Sound On` that I could get response `do something`.

Grep now always find string `Sound On` colored it into red.
But I do not get response from echo command.

```
pc@pc:~$ silan -t 0.1 -s -60d "http://radio.sprejmi.si/" | grep "Sound On" && echo "do something"
Info: signal threshold: 0.001000 ^= -60.000dBFS
0.017438 Sound On
```

Same is if I use top command. I don't get response from echo

```
pc@pc-ESPRIMO-P:~$ top | grep "Mem" && echo "do something"
MiB Mem :   7939,8 total,   3520,2 free,   1131,4 used,   3288,2 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2036,0 total,   2036,0 free,      0,0 used.   6324,2 avail Mem
MiB Mem :   7939,8 total,   3520,0 free,   1131,6 used,   3288,2 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2036,0 total,   2036,0 free,      0,0 used.   6323,9 avail Mem

pc@pc-ESPRIMO-P:~$
```

But if I do this with text file in which is string `Sound On` echo gives me response

```
pc@pc-ESPRIMO-P:~$ cat 1.txt | grep "Sound On" && echo "do something"
0.065329 Sound On
0.065329 Sound On
do something
pc@pc-ESPRIMO-P:~$
```

Comment: `top` is designed for interactive use, and not really suitable for piping to `grep`; try `top -B` if you really want to. I suspect your other problem is something similar. Check if th  `silan` tool has an option or companion utility for scripted batch operation.

Comment: (as for the `top | grep && echo "do something"` case, anything on the right-hand side of the `&&` happens only after `grep` exits, which doesn't happen until `top` exits, which it isn't typically written to do on its own; you could add `-m 1` to the `grep` part to make it exit as soon as a match is found, but generally, `top` should only be run by humans, not by scripts; use `ps` instead when you want to filter output)

Answer (score 2):

In `foo | bar && baz`, `baz` only runs **after `bar` has exited** (and done so with an exit status indicating success).

When `foo` is a program that keeps running indefinitely, and `bar` is a tool like `grep` that keeps running as long as there's something feeding it input, there's never an opportunity for `baz` to be invoked.

(Also, make sure that `silan` is actually writing the string you're looking for to stdout; if it were going to stderr -- as is appropriate for logs meant to be read by a human operator -- `grep` wouldn't see it at all).

---

If you want to force `top` or `silan` to exit as soon as the string you're looking for is found, add `-m 1` to `grep`'s argument list, which tells `grep` to exit when a match is found, which will cause `top`'s next attempt to write to its stdout to fail, causing it to exit in turn:

```
top | grep -m 1 Mem && echo "do something"
```

If you want to let `top` keep going and do something every time `Mem` is seen, then a different approach is called for altogether:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "do something with $line"
done < <(top | grep --line-buffered Mem)
```